# issue with JRuby + OpenURI + HTTPS

Tags: jruby

I have problem with very simple program I'm trying to write using JRuby, Open URI and JRuby-OSSL.

I installed JRuby-OSSL gem using:

```
gem install jruby-openssl
```

and downloaded latest jruby-complete jar (1.6.7).

I have simple script test.rb:

```
require 'jruby/openssl/gem_only'
require 'open-uri'
open('https://google.com')
```

and when I run it like this:

```
java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar test.rb
```

I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Net::HTTP::OpenSSL
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2642
       use_ssl= at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/https.rb:124
      open_http at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:231
    buffer_open at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616
      open_loop at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164
          catch at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1183
      open_loop at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162
       open_uri at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132
           open at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518
           open at file:/Users/mislocin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30
         (root) at test.rb:4
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some details, any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, found my error.

By mistake, I configured GEM_HOME variable pointing to my gem repo instead of GEM_PATH. After configuring GEM_PATH environment variable everything works fine now.

Comment: That's not a good answer in my book. You could have given more details about these paths without showing your actual directory structure. Just a thought. But as of this it's still zero.

Answer (score 1):

try requiring **openssl** instead :

```
require 'openssl'
require 'open-uri'
open('https://google.com')
```

but than of course this probably won't solve you problem.
you `gem install jruby-openssl` among your jruby gems, but than do not use `jruby` but invoke java directly - you should not rely on it resolving gems based on your `ENV` variables.

you also should expect a `SSLError` as you haven't configured it to ignore certificate verification, here's a sample how to get **https://** URIs: https://gist.github.com/1361989

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help, when I try with require 'openssl' I get: LoadError: OpenSSL::SSL requires the jruby-openssl gem. I need to invoke this code from within JVM, that's why I don't use jruby command. Any other ideas?

Comment: what you're trying to do is portably "impossible" as I already touched in my answer. you install the gem into the FS into your jruby's `GEM_HOME` but than use `java -jar` - that can't work (unless it's on a computer with a `GEM_HOME` where the same gem is installed). **jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar** includes a (default) rubygems install (check *META-INF/jruby.home*) you need to get the gem "inside" the jar - you should use https://github.com/jruby/warbler do build an executable jruby jar with some gems in it.